# I having a problem with the mysqli free() member function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have code where I connected to the database like so:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "company");
```

Now when I query the database like so:

```
//query calls to a stored procedure 'user_info' 
$result = $db->query("CALL user_info('$instruc', 'c_register', '$eml', '$pass', '')");
if($result->fetch_array())
{
   //use the results
}
$result->close();

$result = $db->query("CALL user_info('$instruc', 's_login', '$eml', '$pass', '')");
if($result->fetch_array())
{
   //use the results
}
$result->close();
```

I get this error after the first `$result->close();`

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in...

For me to run this other query I have to close the db connection and connect again, then it will work.  I want to know if there is a way I could run the other query without having to disconnect and reconnect to the database.

Answer (score 2):

`free()` removes any data *stored in connection* with the result set, but it doesn't unset the `$result` object itself, so `$result` being still set is perfectly okay.

You should still be able to start a new query using the `$db` object, though. Freeing a result set should not affect the database object itself.

Can you show the full code of the query that fails after you run `free()` on your result object and what error it returns?

Comment: @neo close() closes the database connection. use free() instead, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example given below:

```
$query='select ml_id, list_name from ml_lists order by list_name asc';
$squery=$db->query($query);

    while($rows=$squery->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $rows['list_name'];
    }
}
$squery->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some error handling. if mysqli->query fails it returns `false`, so $result isn't an object, hence the `Fatal error: Call to a member function xyz() on a non-object`.
In that case mysqli->error should contain the error message.

```
//query calls to a stored procedure 'user_info'
$result = $db->query("CALL user_info('$instruc', 'c_register', '$eml', '$pass', '')");
if ( !$result ) {
  die('an error occured: '.$db->error);
}
if($result->fetch_array())
{
  //use the results
}
$result->close();

$result = $db->query("CALL user_info('$instruc', 's_login', '$eml', '$pass', '')");
if ( !$result ) {
  die('an error occured: '.$db->error);
}
if($result->fetch_array())
{
  //use the results
}
$result->close();
```

Comment: I tried that code now I get:  "an error occured: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

Comment: Does `while( $db->next_result() );` before each `$result->close();` fix the problem?